# Can't run TeX Live's tlmgr in a github action

Tags: tlmgr

Github Actions have made it much easier to automatically regenerate a book or website with LaTeX graphics, but it seems to have problems with `tlmgr`, in that nothing I tried makes it actually work.

I'm installing TeX Live the usual way:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xzdec libpoppler-glib-dev texlive texlive-xetex -y
```

And then I bootstrap tlmgr the usual way, too:

```
tlmgr --version
tlmgr init-usertree
sudo tlmgr update --all
```

This leads to the following output:

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr revision 46207 (2018-01-04 19:34:36 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/share/texlive
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2017
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
Cannot determine type of tlpdb from /home/runner/texmf!
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2020)
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Reading through https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html doesn't really offer much in a way forward here, since it describes some intensive manual intervention, which isn't an option for a CI/CD run. How do I make `tlmgr`/TeX Live play nice in this situation?

(And in case I'm thinking about this the wrong way, I need xelatex and pdfcrop for my CI task, and would *love* to do that without ever needing tlmgr. However, it looks like the only way to get pdfcrop installed is via texlive-full, which is nearly 5GB and so isn't an option as part of a CI runner)

Comment: Basically the `tlmgr` you get when you install TeX live from the Debian/Ubuntu repositories can not update system-installed packages. If you install TeX live via `apt`/`apt-get` you are basically stuck with the package version your Linux distribution ships. If you want to live on the cutting edge, you need to install a 'vanilla' TeX live from TUG.org (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864)

Comment: Here's how the LaTeX team use Travis CI (https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/master/.travis.yml, https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/master/support/texlive.sh, https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/master/support/texlive.profile) to install a vanilla TeX live. (Slightly simpler setup is at https://github.com/josephwright/csquotes/blob/master/.travis.yml, https://github.com/josephwright/csquotes/blob/master/support/install-texlive.sh, https://github.com/josephwright/csquotes/blob/master/support/texlive.profile), but the idea is the same.

Comment: According to https://packages.debian.org/stretch/texlive-extra-utils `pdfcrop` is in `texlive-extra-utils`, which might save you from having to install `texlive-full`

Comment: That's a good find - I tried searching the debian package system and didn't get anything useful: how did you find that?

Comment: I searched "pdfcrop ubuntu", found https://askubuntu.com/q/864474/57634, then Googled `texlive-extra-utils`. I guess a more direct method would have been to search on `packages.debian.org` https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=pdfcrop (you need to search "package contents" or "descriptions", the other options don't turn up anything for `pdfcrop`)

Comment: The heck? That's literally what I did 20 minutes ago and got an empty list... =_= Want to make that an answer? Because that's the simplest solution and definitely works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are only after `tlmgr` usage for `pdfcrop` you can just install `texlive-extra-utils` instead.

Often one can find TeX live packages/component by searching on `packages.debian.org`. Just make sure to select "package contents" or "descriptions".

e.g. https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=pdfcrop

Searching "package names" is usually not enough.

---

As mentioned in the comments the tlmgr you get when you install TeX live from the Debian/Ubuntu repositories can basically not update system-installed packages. If you install TeX live via `apt`/`apt-get` you are basically stuck with the package version your Linux distribution ships (which are *usually* not updated, unless you are on a rolling release?). If you want to live on the cutting edge, you need to install a 'vanilla' TeX live from TUG.org ([How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864)).

Comment: Good point, I bet I searched with just "package names"... Thanks for the help!